# Track peaks of two or more moving pulse generators

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, signal-detection, information-extraction

I want to disentangle the signals of two or more moving pulse sources using recordings of these pulses (see pictures).
Example plots (4 panels per example to stretch the x axis a bit, the peaks of each detected pulse are labelled with orange and green dots):
One pulse source:
[image: One pulse generator]
Two pulse sources:
[image: Two pulse generators]

The difficulty is that these pulses are extremely similar, so I can't tell them apart using their shapes. As you can see, the two sources can be distinguished visually, based on the amplitude of the pulses, and how they change over time (they move in and out of detection range). This is because the peaks of the pulses have a certain spatial coherence for each pulse source.

Is there a good solution to tell the two pulse sources in the second picture apart by tracking the peaks? I guess, a straightforward approach would be to evaluate the similarity of two adjacent peaks in amplitude and time and then, based on some reproducible threshold, to group them together or assign them to different sources. Maybe something like the nearest-neighbour search is applicable? I'm relatively new to this, so I'd be happy for any suggestions that help me here.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider asking your question at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Thank you, I've done that now